# Using Lodash debounce in React to prevent requesting data as long as the user is typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I don't want to fire requests as long as the user is typing. My code should throttle requests so that when the user types quickly, it will fire one request with the latest input value instead of many.

For now when I'm typing "test" it fires 4 different requests:

1. "t"
2. "te"
3. "tes"
4. "test"

So I found lodash _.debounce and _.throttle ( [https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce] ) but don't really understand how I can inplement it to my code. Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import './style.css';

import { search } from '../../actions/';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchTerm: '' };
  }

  startSearch(query) {
    const storedTerms = this.props.searchedTerm;
    let foundDuplicate = false;

    if (storedTerms.length === 0 && query) {
      return this.props.search(query);
    }

    if (storedTerms.length !== 0 && query) {
      const testDuplicate = storedTerms.map(term => term === query);
      foundDuplicate = testDuplicate.some(element => element);
    }

    if (storedTerms.length !== 0 && !query) {
      return false;
    }

    if (foundDuplicate) {
      return false;
    }

  return this.props.search(query);
}

handleInputChange(term) {
  this.setState({ searchTerm: term });
  this.startSearch(term);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="Search-bar">
      <input
        value={this.state.searchTerm}
        onChange={event => this.handleInputChange(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    searchedTerm: state.searchedTerm,
    savedData: state.savedData,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ search }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

---

EDIT:

Thx to Sagiv b.g, I'm adding some explanation:

ok, so the user should type more than 2 letters && also my app should wait minimum 2 seconds before starting ajax request

---

**EDIT2:
Thx to Sagiv b.g, for great solution!**

I've changed my code like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './style.css';

import { search } from '../../actions/';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { inputValue: '' };

    this.startSearch = _.debounce(this.startSearch, 2000);
  }

  startSearch(query) {
    const storedTerms = this.props.searchedTerm;
    let foundDuplicate = false;

    if (storedTerms.length === 0 && query) {
      return this.props.search(query);
    }

    if (storedTerms.length !== 0 && query) {
      const testDuplicate = storedTerms.map(term => term === query);
      foundDuplicate = testDuplicate.some(element => element);
    }

    if (storedTerms.length !== 0 && !query) {
      return false;
    }

    if (foundDuplicate) {
      return false;
    }

    return this.props.search(query);
  }

  onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: value });
    if (value.length > 2) {
      this.startSearch(value);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Search-bar">
        <input
          placeholder="Type something to search GitHub"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    searchedTerm: state.searchedTerm,
    savedData: state.savedData,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ search }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

---

**Last Bug to deal with**

But it has one last bug, that I don't know how to get rid off. When the user wants to change search query and uses backspace to erase search field, my app always fires unexpectedly another API request.
Here is an example:

https://youtu.be/uPEt0hHDOAI

**Any ideas how I can get rid of that behavior?**

Comment: when you say "_as long as the user is typing..._", can you explain how exactly do you wish to determine when a user is about to type another letter? some users type 1 letter per 0.5 a second and other may type slower. you can't really be sure when a user is done typing. you can throttle the ajax request to some unit of time (1.5 second?) and / or minimum length of string and hope for the best.

Comment: ok, so user should type more then 2 letters && also my app should wait 2 seconds before starting ajax request

Comment: @MountainConqueror do you remember how you solved that unexpected behavior ? if so please tell me how i'm stuck now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well this is easy with lodash `_.debounce`.
You wrap your method with it and pass the milliseconds you want to wait.
As for the minimum length of the input, just invoke the new method only if the length is above 2.

Here is a small running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: '',
      inputValue: ''
    };

    this.updateMessage = _.debounce(this.updateMessage, 2000);
  }


  onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: value });
    if (value.length > 2) {
      this.updateMessage(value);
    }
  }


  updateMessage = message => this.setState({ message });

  render() {
    const { message, inputValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input placeholder="type something..." value={inputValue} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <hr/>
        <div>server call >> wait 2 seconds & min length of 2</div>
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, but I have one last bug to deal with. Should I accept your answer and create new StackOverflow question? Here is my problem -> https://youtu.be/uPEt0hHDOAI

Comment: Seems like its not directly related to this question (seems like a redux issue). So i think a new question is with relevant code example is better