# Reactjs Search after onChange

Tags: reactjs, search, fetch

I have implemented a little search functionality in my reactjs application. 
The Problem is, that my "searchHandler" function is triggered after every single letter the user enters in the textfield... So e.g. for the term "Lorem" my function is fetching 5 times from my api :(

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
const { scaleDown } = transitions;

function searchingFor(term){

return function(x){
return x.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
x.body.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
}

 }  


class ViewAll extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    term: '',
    mounted: true,
    tracks: [],
    hasMoreItems: true,
    page: 2,

  }

  this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
  this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
  this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);


 }

  loadContent() {
    var requestUrl = this.props.url;
    fetch(requestUrl + this.state.page + '&_limit=3').then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }) .then((tracks)=>{
        this.setState({ tracks: this.state.tracks.concat(tracks)});
        this.setState({page: this.state.page + 1});

        if(this.state.page === 6){
         this.setState({hasMoreItems: false})
       }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("There has been an error");
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

var requestUrl = this.props.url;
fetch(requestUrl + '1&_limit=3')
    .then((response)=>{
    return response.json();
}) .then((data)=>{
    this.setState({tracks : data});

})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("There has been an error");
});

//this.focus();

 }
  searchHandler(event){
    this.setState({term: event.target.value});

    var requestUrl = 'https://questdb.herokuapp.com/all?q='
    fetch(requestUrl + this.state.term).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }) .then((tracks)=>{
        this.setState({ tracks: this.state.tracks.concat(tracks)});


    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("There has been an error");
    });

  }

   focus() {
   this.textInput.focus();
 }


    keyPress(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13){
          console.log('value', e.target.value);
          // put the login here
       }
    }    


render() {   


  const {term, data, tracks} = this.state;

  const loader = <div className="loader2"> </div>;

  var items = [];
  const imageUrl = require(`../assets/Book.jpg`)

  tracks.filter(searchingFor(term)).map(function(title, i)
{
    items.push(
            <div>
              <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Paper style={{ borderRadius: "2em",
                  background: '#ffffff'
                }} zDepth={1} >

          <ItemViewAll
            key={title.id}
              />
      </Paper>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }, this);



    return (
      <div>    

            <Fade in={true}  timeout={1000}>

<div >

  <MuiThemeProvider>

    <TextField hintText='Bot suchen...'

         type="Text"
         onChange={this.searchHandler}
         value={term}
         underlineFocusStyle={{borderColor: '#B00020', borderWidth: 3}}
         underlineStyle={{borderColor: '#B00020', borderWidth: 1.5, top: '45px'}}
         hintStyle={{fontSize: '8.1vw', fontFamily: 'Anton', color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)'}}
         inputStyle={{fontSize: '8.1vw', fontFamily: 'Anton', color: '#ffffff'}}
         ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
         style={{caretColor: '#ffffff', width: '90%', maginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto', marginTop: '12%' }}
         InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
         />


     </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
      </Fade>   



    <InfiniteScroll
       pageStart={1}
       loadMore={this.loadContent.bind(this)}
       hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
       initialLoad={true}

      >


              {items}
         </InfiniteScroll>    


</div>
    )
  }
}

export default ViewAll;
```

Here you can check out the Website with the broken search function. As you can see the items are shown double or even triple... After the textfield is emptied, the search results should be removed and only the normal fetched ones should be shown.

https://www.genko.de   (use the mobile version in chrome)

Thank you :)

Comment: Use lodash debounce https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046061/using-lodash-debounce-in-react-to-prevent-requesting-data-as-long-as-the-user-is

Comment: you're using onChange, so the event is called when the input changes. What is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lodash debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046061/using-lodash-debounce-in-react-to-prevent-requesting-data-as-long-as-the-user-is). It is used for this exact use case

Sample:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

class TableSearch extends Component {

  //********************************************/

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        value: props.value
    }

    this.changeSearch = debounce(this.props.changeSearch, 250)
  }

  //********************************************/

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value

    this.setState({ value: val }, () => {
      this.changeSearch(val)
    })
  }

  //********************************************/

  render() {

    return (
        <input
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            value = {this.props.value}
        />
    )
  }

  //********************************************/

}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide an example, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need full lodash package you can write it yourself:

```
function debounce(f, ms) {

  let timer = null;

  return function (...args) {
    const onComplete = () => {
      f.apply(this, args);
      timer = null;
    }

    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(onComplete, ms);
  };
}
```

The first arg (f) is your function which should not be performed more often than
second arg (ms) - amount of ms ). So in your case you can write your handler in next way:

```
handleChange = debounce((e) => {
  const val = e.target.value

  this.setState({ value: val }, () => {
    this.changeSearch(val)
  })
}, 1000) // second arg (1000) is your amount of ms
```